# Set x-axis labels to dates when plotting time series

Tags: r

```
x=read.table(text="    Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4  
2010  1.8  8.0  6.0  3.0  
2011  2.0 11.0  7.0  3.5  
2012  2.5 14.0  8.0  4.2  
2013  3.0 15.2  9.5  5.0",
    sep="",header=TRUE)  
y<-ts(as.vector(as.matrix(x)),frequency=4,start=c(2010,1))  
plot.ts(y)  
time<-seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"),length.out=20,by="3 months")  
axis(1, at = time)
```

when i draw the graph ,i want to add date in x axis,why my `axis(1, at = time)` can't add the date data in x axis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `axis(1, at=time)` you're telling R to plot the x axis with labels at points given by `time`. However, `time` is a vector of characters, not numbers.

In general, you call `axis(1, at=..., labels=...)` indicating the actual labels and where to place them along the axis. In your case, your call to `plot.ts` implicitly sets the x-axis limits to `2010` and `2013.75`, so your `at` parameter should reflect those limits.

So you want to call `axis` saying that the labels are `time` and the positions are `2010, 2010.25, 2010.50 ...`, that is, `seq(from=2010, to=2013.25, by=0.25)`. A general solution is this one:

```
plot.ts(y,axes=F) # don't plot the axes yet
axis(2) # plot the y axis
axis(1, labels=time, at=seq(from=2010, by=0.25, length.out=length(time)) )
box() # and the box around the plot
```